# i can not upload img to DRF api using Angular 6

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

i'm new to DRF ,i build a simple api depends on the official documentation 
evrything works good but when i want to upload img file 
the request.data is empty

```
request.data = ---->  <QueryDict: {}>
```

so if any one can help

angular .serviece.ts

```
const httpOptions_multipart = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': 'Token 28----------------------8d01ab33e1df'
   })
};

UploadImage(img):Observable<Image> {    
  console.log(img);
  return this.http.put<Image>(this.profileUrl, img, httpOptions_multipart)
}
```

Angular .component.ts

```
    fileToUpload: File = null;

    handleFileInput(files: FileList) {

    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    console.log('get item ');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event:any){
      this.imgUrl = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload)
    }

    uploadFileToActivity(){
    this.productservice.UploadImage(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data =>{
     console.log(data);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
          });
    }
```

django rest framework model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics', blank=True)

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    @decorators.action(
       detail=True,
       methods=['PUT'],
       serializer_class=ProfilePicSerializer,
       parser_classes=(MultiPartParser,)
    )
    def pic(self, request, pk):
        print ('request.data = ----> ',request.data)
        obj = self.get_object()
        print(obj)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(obj, data=request.data,
                                       partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return response.Response(serializer.data)
        return response.Response(serializer.errors,
                                 status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'bio', 'pic']
        read_only_fields = ['pic']


class ProfilePicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['pic']
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        # 'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        # 'rest_framework.parsers.FileUploadParser',
        # 'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',

    ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
}
```

or if there is other way easier than 
i'm just need any way to upload image 
i'm new to programming thanks

Comment: This is a lot of code, and it looks like you want someone to debug it for you. What have you tried? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: is request.File also null ??

Comment: Try upload the file using postman. If its success then the problem is in your angular code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is put method not support multi-part form data  in angular 6. Use post method instead of put will resolve your problem.

Comment: thank you so much , i found that the problem is when i use  FormData to make a post i should not use  HttpHeaders.Content-Type because the browser will make it for me